# No Interface : ID3D12Device2

Tags: visual-c++, directx, directx-12

[image]

```
if (FAILED(hr = D3D12CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, IID_PPV_ARGS(p_ppD3D12Device2))))
{
    // hr = nointerface  
}
```

After checking the MS document, I knew the the problem maybe can be solved by update the windows.

GPU: `Nvidia Quadro P4000`

OS: `Windows 2016 Server`

But I have a few questions.

1. That mean some games using the `ID3D12Device2` can not be played by some Win10 PC.
2. Which version windows update I need to apply? (I don't want to update irrelevant stuff.)
3. What is the advantage of using `ID3D12Device2 、3、 4` instead of `ID3D12Device`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Windows 2016 Server" is the equivalent to Windows 10 Anniversary Update (14393). That version of Windows will therefore support `ID3D12Device` and `ID3D12Device1` interfaces, but nothing newer.

If you upgraded to "Windows 2016 Server, Version 1709" then it would be the equivalent to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (16299) which supports `ID3D12Device`, `ID3D12Device1`,`ID3D12Device2`, and `ID3D12Device3`.

PC games use whatever version of the device is supported by the version of the Windows 10 OS they deem required to support for their title. If they want to support older versions of Windows, then they use the oldest interface they want (typically `ID3D12Device` is fine for most basic graphics), and then use `QueryInterface` to conditional test for newer support if they make use of it. They will then need fallback codepaths if they want to run without that feature.

```
ComPtr<ID3D12Device> device;
if (FAILED(hr = D3D12CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&device))))
{
    // Not on Windows 10 or the is no default video device that supports DirectX 12
}

...

ComPtr<ID3D12Device2> device2;
hr = device.As(device2);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // This system supports DirectX 12.2
}
```

Most of the newer versions of the device expose new functionality that you must check for first via `ID3D12Device::CheckFeatureSupport` to confirm that the *driver* actually supports the new feature on the current hardware, so just checking for the interface version isn't sufficient.

See [SystemInfo](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/System/SystemInfoUWP) and [DxCapsViewer](https://github.com/microsoft/DxCapsViewer) for more about the various 'optional' features.

> Windows 10 does not ship 'new features' via Windows Update piecemeal. They are shipped as part of newer versions of the OS. If you were using Windows Server 2019 which is the equivalent to Windows 10 October 2018 Update (17763) you would have support up through `ID3D12Device4` which supports *DirectX Raytracing* with proper hardware. There's not yet a release of Windows Server that provides `ID3D12Device8` (Amplification & Mesh Shader, DirectX Raytracing 1.1, Variable Rate Shaders) support that shipped in Windows 10 May 2020 (19041). Remember DirectX 12 is considered a 'consumer feature'.

**Having said all that**, you don't need `ID3D12Device2` support to learn DirectX 12. The method exposed by that interface, `CreatePipelineState`, creates a Pipeline State Object (PSO) from a `D3D12_PIPELINE_STATE_STREAM_DESC`. This is used for advanced shader scenarios like Amplification & Mesh Shaders, but you don't have to use it. For example, all of [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) works with the base `ID3D12Device` interface.

A larger concern is that you may not have a video card & driver that supports DirectX 12. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/) for the recommended way to create the DirectX 12 device.

> BTW, `D3D12CreateDevice` supports being able to directly create newer versions of the interface for cases where you already know the target platform supports it. For example, using DirectX 12 on Xbox or if you are a UWP/Desktop Bridge app that has a particular version of Windows 10 set as the minimum supported OS.